# Finding numbers in a list of permutations based on the position of one of the numbers in the list

Tags: python, list, math, permutation, python-itertools

I've been coding a program that solves a maths problem with specific conditions.

In this maths problem, there are seven slots. At the beginning, the first three slots are occupied by the numbers 1, 2 and 3. There is an empty slot in the middle. The next three are numbers 4, 5 and 6. Seven slots altogether.

The goal of the problem is for the 1 2 and 3 to switch places with the 4 5 and 6. Only one number can be moved at a time. It can move over another number into an empty slot (the zero) or move sideways switching with an empty slot.

Below is a visualisation of the start:

1 2 3 0 4 5 6

---

The desired outcome is shown below:

4 5 6 0 1 2 3

---

Keep in mind that it does not have to be in this order, as long as 4 5 6 is on one side and 1 2 3 is on the other with 0 in the middle.

The program that we are creating uses itertools for a list of permutations. Then, based on the position of the zero, finds a permutation that suits the next move.

What I need is for specific combinations to be extracted (output) from this list, based on the position of zeroes within the combinations. Below is the code so far.

```
import time
import itertools

nonStop = True
answerList = [1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6]

combinations = itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6])

while nonStop == True:
    for value in combinations:
        i = 0
        print(value)
        i += 1
        time.sleep(2)
```

Thanks in advance. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems like you haven't attempted anything to extracted (output) from this list, based on the position of zeroes within the combinations. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: You're calling your permutations `combinations` o_O

Comment: What are the `combinations` supposed to do here that solves this problem explicitly? Also, it doesn't look like your editing anything in `answerList`, nor is there any `break` condition in your `while` loop. One thing that can be helpful is talk yourself through the steps required to move one number, and try to execute that in code. That way you aren't trying to solve the *whole* problem in one go

Comment: Also how is your answer represented? A list of states that lead you to your final goal? Why did you choose to compute all possible permutations of your starting list?

Comment: My understanding now since Rory's help is that the combinations are stored in order to be read by the program to make the next move. This is only the beginning of the code but the answer list would be the dictionary essentially. Thanks for the advice on the break in the while loop. All of the positions from the start to end would be printed. Yes, one number moves one or two slots into an empty slot, but they can only move in one direction from the start, not backwards. Imagine like this >>>_<<<

Answer (score 0):

Here is some high-level advice on your program. I'll assume that on each move the zero will swap places with a number that is one or two slots distance from the zero. I'll also assume that you want to find the smallest number of moves that takes you from the initial list to a "desired outcome" and that the printout is to show all the positions from the starting position to the desired outcome.

If you know graph theory (also called network theory) you could easily solve your problem by performing a breadth-first search from your starting position to any desired position. The nodes in your graph are the 5,040 possible permutations, and two nodes have an edge between them if you can go from one position to the other in one move.

If you don't know graph theory, you can use this following approach. You can use two overall data structures: a queue (such as [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.deque)) and a dictionary. Put the initial position into the queue. Also put it as a key in the dictionary with the value `None`.

Then run a loop. In each run through the loop, remove one position from the queue. There will be at most four possible moves from this position: swap the zero with the item 2 left, 1 left, 1 right, or 2 right of the zero. (If the zero is at or near an end, the possible moves will be fewer.) For each of those moves, if the resulting position is not already in the dictionary, add it to the queue and the dictionary. The dictionary entry's value is the position you just took from the queue. If the resulting position is already in the dictionary, do nothing.

Now check if the resulting position is a "desired result". If not, continue the loop. If it is, use the dictionary to save all the moves from your desired result back to the initial position. Then print those positions in the desired order, and you are done--break the loop.

Note three things about this approach. First, if any sequence of moves reaches a desired result, this approach will print one of the shortest sequences. Second, not all permutations of the original position are generated. Permutations are generated one at a time until a desired result is reached--there is no need for more. Third, no printing is done until all the moves are done and the good moves have been picked out. This is because most moves will not prove to be useful, so we wait until we know which the useful ones are.

If you want more information, show some more work of your own. But before that, tell me if I understood the rules of your problem correctly.

Comment: Hi Rory, that was very informative. Thanks a lot! You understood it exactly, and by dictionary do you mean a record of the moves made? So essentially, the only thing I need to figure out is how the computer actually makes the moves. If the initial position is in the queue, how are the next moves made with Python? Would something like an array work with preset conditions so it can only make certain moves? Could you also please expand on the edges? Thanks

Comment: @IanHeng: By "dictionary" I mean a Python dictionary, where each key is a position whose value is the position that led to the given position in one move. This links the positions together--these links are the "edges" in the the theoretical graph. You may need to study Python dictionaries and graphs/networks further--you should know these concepts before tackling a problem of this difficulty. I'll not explain calculating the moves until you show more of your own programming attempts. You need to show more effort in code.

Comment: @IanHeng: Why are you so reluctant to show more of your work? I have already written a Python program that solves your problem, and the program uses the approach I gave you. It examines `3483` positions, not all of them, before reaching and printing the answer.